# Using UI-router, carousel doesn't show and stops working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router, carousel

```js
   // app.js
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    
    $stateProvider
        
        // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'home.html'
        })
    // nested list with custom controller
    //.state('home.list',{
     // url:'/list',
    //templateUrl: 'partial-home-list.html',
    //controller: function($scope){
     // $scope.dogs = ['malkee', 'macky', 'xya'];
     //}
     //})
     // nested list with just some random string data
    //.state('home.paragraph', {
      //  url: '/paragraph',
        //template: 'I could sure use a drink right now.'
   // })

        
        // ABOUT PAGE AND MULTIPLE NAMED VIEWS =================================
        .state('products', {
           url: '/products',
     templateUrl: 'products.html'
        })
  
   .state('portfolio', {
           url: '/portfolio',
     templateUrl: 'portfolio.html'
        })
  
  .state('about', {
           url: '/about',
     templateUrl: 'about.html'
        })
  
  .state('blog', {
           url: '/blog',
     templateUrl: 'blog.html'
        })
  
  .state('services', {
           url: '/services',
     templateUrl: 'services.html'
        })
  
  .state('contact', {
           url: '/contact',
     templateUrl: 'contact.html'
        });
        
});
```

```html
<!--This is the index html-->

<body ng-app="routerApp">

<!-- NAVIGATION -->
<div ng-include="'nav.html'"></div>

<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<div class="container">

    <!-- THIS IS WHERE WE WILL INJECT OUR CONTENT ============================== -->
    <div ui-view></div>

</div>
<div ng-include="'footer.html'"></div>
</body>

<!--this is the HTML where the slider is-->


<div class="our-clients">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="our-clients-head text-center">
    <h3>Our Clients</h3>
   </div>
   <!---strat-image-cursuals---->
                  <div class="scroll-slider">            
       <div class="nbs-flexisel-container">
       <div class="nbs-flexisel-inner">
       <ul class="flexiselDemo3 nbs-flexisel-ul" style="left: -253.6px; display: block;">                              
       <li><img src="images/c1.png"></li>
       <li><img src="images/c2.png"></li>
       <li><img src="images/c3.png"></li>
       <li><img src="images/c4.png"></li>
       <li><img src="images/c5.png"></li>
       <li><img src="images/c5.jpg"></li>
       <li><img src="images/c3.jpg"></li>
       <li><img src="images/c4.jpg"></li>
       </ul>
       <div class="nbs-flexisel-nav-left" style="display:none"></div>
       <div class="nbs-flexisel-nav-right" style="display:none"></div></div></div> 
       <div class="clear"> </div>      
        <!---strat-image-cursuals---->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexisel.js"></script>
        <!---End-image-cursuals---->
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function() {
            $(".flexiselDemo3").flexisel({
                visibleItems: 4,
                animationSpeed: 1000,
                autoPlay: true,
                autoPlaySpeed: 3000,            
                pauseOnHover: true,
                enableResponsiveBreakpoints: true,
                responsiveBreakpoints: { 
                    portrait: { 
                        changePoint:480,
                        visibleItems: 1
                    }, 
                    landscape: { 
                        changePoint:640,
                        visibleItems: 2
                    },
                    tablet: { 
                        changePoint:768,
                        visibleItems: 3
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
      <!---->
      <!---->
      </div>    
   </div>

    <!---//End-signin---->
  </div>
  <div class="testimonials-section">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="testimonials-section-head text-center">
     <h3>Testimonials</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="members">
     <div class="col-md-4 member1">
      <img src="images/mem.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="text text-center">
       <h4>John Doe</h4>
       <p>CEO, Company.com</p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-8 description">
      <div class="course_demo">
            <ul id="flexiselDemo4"> 
     <li>
      <div class="client-text">
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostru.</p>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <div class="client-text">  
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</p>
      </div>
     </li> 
     <li>
      <div class="client-text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud. </p>
      </div>
     </li>                                                                 
    </ul>

   </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(window).load(function() {
    $("#flexiselDemo4").flexisel({
     visibleItems: 1,
     animationSpeed: 1000,
     autoPlay: true,
     autoPlaySpeed: 3000,      
     pauseOnHover: true,
     enableResponsiveBreakpoints: true,
        responsiveBreakpoints: { 
         portrait: { 
          changePoint:480,
          visibleItems: 1
         }, 
         landscape: { 
          changePoint:640,
          visibleItems: 1
         },
         tablet: { 
          changePoint:768,
          visibleItems: 1
         }
        }
       });
       
   });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexisel.js"></script>
```

I am making an angular app using UI-router.

Everything is working fine, but I am facing a problem with carousel. There is a page named `home.html` which is being viewed in `index.html` via UI-router. All content shows great, but the carousel doesn't show, and another carousel doesn't work. But if I paste the same code in `index.html`. Every single element shows up including the carousel itself. I have checked all the links etc., all is good. Please help.

Comment: Could you please provide some code? Something with your code must be wrong so we need to see it in order to help you.

Comment: Make sure you are specifying a controller (perhaps the index.html has ng-controller set but the other views don't).

Comment: Hi I have inserted the code into the post. Please do check

Comment: I have commented both the HTML via comment lines. Please do take care of that. Thanks